# Matlab build graph from bwtraceboundary and find shortest path

Tags: algorithm, matlab, graph-theory, dijkstra

I used `bwtraceboundary` where the image shows the resulting boundary path.

[image]

Overall, it works great and actually does exactly what I expect, but I later run into problems with the 90 degree turn and protrusion that extends furthest right.

I did find an algorithm on [Matlab file exchange](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/20025-dijkstra-s-minimum-cost-path-algorithm) (`dijkstra`) that might just do the trick, where the description says

> calculates the shortest (least cost) path along edges of a graph using Dijkstra's Algorithm

After reviewing the function inputs and examples, I believe I could use the function in the following manor

```
[costs,paths] = dijkstra(V,E,SID,FID)
```

where

> V   is a Nx2 (or Nx3) matrix of x,y,(z) coordinates
>
> E   is a Px2 matrix containing a list of edge connections

The start index (`SID`) and final index (`FID`) can simply be defined as the top and bottom indices.

I know the x-y pixel indices from `bwtraceboundary`, so I have `V` covered.

The problem is I don't know how to easily generate `E`, the list of edge connections. I believe the list of edge connections should result in a graph that looks like the following

[image]

After I figure out `E` and run the algorithm, the path should follow the green nodes in the image below

[image]

In the end, the red nodes responsible for the 90 degree turn and protrusion can be identified using `ismember` comparing the original node indices with those of the shortest path connecting the green nodes, thus completing my objective.

My questions is, how do I generate `E`, the list of edge connections that is input into the algorithm to give my desired result?

I should note that I don't have the "graph toolbox" in Matlab, so this has to be done manually.

Comment: This is a duplicate of your previous question. It would have been better to improve that question rather than create a new one. My suggestion from the previous question still stands; Dijkstra is overkill in this case because the edge weights are all 1.

Comment: I do agree, Dijkstra sounds a bit overkill for this particular example, but it should still work. I didn't dive into the source code mentioned above, but it seems that it offers an optimized approach where I don't need to enter the full adjacency matrix. That being said, my actual problem is much more complex and likely to evolve into one which does require weights, so I just assume start with Dijkstra now, with a simple application.

Comment: So did that Dijkstra implementation work? What version of MATLAB do you have, because if you've got at least 2015b you can use `shortestpath` instead.

Comment: I've only got 2013. At lot of the graph type functions that show up in a search aren't available, so I've had to resort to alternatives. I did get the Dijkstra working, but as I stated in my question, the trick is to define E properly. When I have more time I'll post my solution and let others help improve it.

Comment: Hm... do you happen to have the Image Processing toolbox? I think I might have some code I can reuse.

Comment: I mean, I can do it without the Image Processing toolbox, but it would probably be a bit easier with it.

Comment: I started with `bwtraceboundary` to extract the boundary info, which I believe is in the image processing toolbox. My objective is to then clean up that boundary. As I said, I'll post my solution early next week when I have more time.